# images not found assetics load - symfony2

Tags: php, html, css, symfony

I have cloned a Symfony2 project on my local machine.

I got it up and running but assets in my `web/Resources` folder won't load (be it images or json files).

I have noticed that after running `assetic:dump` the css and js files are placed into the `web` folder and can be accessed from my app at:

localhost:8000/localFolder/web/app_dev.php/css/725c7d7_inuit.min_1.css?version=4.22

I have tried to place my images in the `web` folder and in the `web/Resources/public/images` folder as suggested in the Symfony good practices. However when I try to access my image with this link:
​

```
http://localhost:8000/localFolder/web/Resources/public/images/phone-service/on-the-clock.jpg
```

it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add your images file (same for css file and javascript file) in 
Resources/public/images( same for css : Resources/public/css, js files: Resources/public/js) under your bundle.

Like this:

> AppBundle/Resources/public/images

And run this command to generate resources in your web folder

```
php app/console assets:install
```

Note that you should run this command line after every modification in your public folder.

if you don't want to make this every time and attribute --symlink

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink
```

Comment: I tried your method, it actually load them in the `web/bundles` with the: `php app/console assets:install --symlink` but my site can't find them. I call them like that in my code: `{{ asset('Resources/public/images/my_image.png') }}`

Comment: No you should call them like this : asset('bundles/BUNDLENAME/images/my_image.png') // Change BUNDLENAME with your name bundle